# Empty Entity after data retrieving from MySQL DB

Tags: java, jpa, entity, querydsl

I have the following Entity

```
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Privilege", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class Privilege implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8357379972506504809L;

private Long privilegeId;
private String name;
private String description;

public Privilege() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "privilegeID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return this.privilegeId;
}

public void setId(Long privilegeId) {
    this.privilegeId = privilegeId;
}


@Column(name = "name", unique = true, length = 45)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Column(name = "description", length = 65535)
@Type(type="text")
public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

}
```

which maps a table in a MySQL DB.
I'm trying to retrieve the data though the following QueryDSL code

```
public Privilege findByName(final String name) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Privilege workgroupPrivilege = new JPAQuery(getEntityManager())
                .from(privilege)
                .where(privilege.name.eq(name))
                .uniqueResult(privilege);
        if (workgroupPrivilege == null)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Cannot find entity "
                    + Privilege.class.getCanonicalName()
                    + " with name <" + name + ">");
        else
            return workgroupPrivilege;
    }
```

The problem is that the `findByName()` code returns me an instance of the Privilege Entity object but the data in its fields are null. 
This means that the Entity-DB Table binding is correctly done (otherwhise I would have had a null Privilege Entity instance).

EDIT:

The web app adds this field to the empty instance of Privilege

```
handler = org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@48f52e0b
```

May this added field be the key to solve the problem?

What can be the problem for you ?

Comment: How do you determine that its fields are null? Don't use you debugger to do that. Use workgroupPrivilege.getId() / getName() / getDescription().

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the debugger's variable view which doesn't retrieve the values of the fields. I lost my day with this problem and the problem wasn't there at all! 

But why does Eclipse's variable view behave this strange?

Comment: What you looked at was an instance of a dynamic lazy proxy, which extends your entity, but delegates all its method calls to an actual instance of your class. Those proxies are used to implement lazy loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger was showing me no data because of lazy data loading.